# how to save frame position in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, multiple-monitors, aquamacs

When I'm using Emacs, I sometimes connect my MacBook to an external monitor. I then create a new, second frame, which I drag to the external monitor and then maximize.

The result is that within Emacs, I have two maximized frames, one on my laptop display and one on my external monitor.

I'd like to save this configuration so I don't have to do this manually each time. Ideally I could restore the frame positions with one keystroke every time I connect my external monitor.

How do I do this? I use Aquamacs on OSX.

Comment: This may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11460472/722238

Answer (score 3):

Since Emacs 24 you can use `desktop-save-mode` [Session management](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html#Saving-Emacs-Sessions)

Answer (score 2):

Try the development version of Emacs 24. Juanma Barranquero is currently implementing frame restoration for Emacs desktops. The code is still changing, but a recent build should give you something that is of use for what you want to do.